# Looking through a list of lists for specific values

Tags: python-3.x, list

I need reada .txt file and find a specific pattern of T's, namely T's arranged in a cross-pattern.

Here's what I've done so far, and its output when I print is below:

```
def find_treasure(mapfile):
    lst = []
    with open(mapfile, 'r') as rf:
        for line in rf:
            lst.append(line.split())
    print(lst)
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UWRoo.png)
My initial idea was to do something like using 2 for loops to go through each item in the list and then look at each letter/ character in the item itself, but I kept getting list index range errors or its not working at all.

```
for i in range(len(lst)):
    for j in range(len(lst[i])):
        if lst[i][j] == 'T':
            print('WHy')
        else:
            print('why am i here why')
```

Do you guys have any advice?

EDIT: Sample input:

```
WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW.TTT..^^^^...WWWWWWWW
WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW...T..^^^^....WWWWWWWW
WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW......^^^......WWWWWWW
WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW..T.....^^^^..T.WWWWWWW
WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW........^^^^..T.WWWWWWW
WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW........^^^....T.WWWWWWW
WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW........^^^......WWWWWWW
WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW.....^^^^.....WWWWWWWW
WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW.....^^^......WWWWWWWW
WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW....^^......WWWWWWWWW
WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW......^.....WWWWWWWWWW
WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW............WWWWWWWWWWW
WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW....T......WWWWWWWWWWWWW
WWWWW...WWWWWWWWWWWWW..T.T.....WWWWWWWWWWWWW
WWWW..TTT.WWWWWWWWWWW...T.....WWWWWWWWWWWWWW
WWWWW.......WWWWWWWWWWW......WWWWWWWWWWWWWWW
WWWWWWWW...T.WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW
WWWWWWWWW....WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW
WWWWWWWWWW.T.WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW
WWWWWWWWWWW.WWWWWWWWWW.....WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW
WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW....T..WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW
WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW.TTT..WWWWWWWWWWWWWWW
WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW..T..WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW
WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW...WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW
WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW
WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW
WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW
W: WATER                                    
T: TREE                                     
.: GRASS                                    
^: MOUNTAIN
```

And the expected output is: `(21,25)`

Comment: Can you edit your question and put there sample input (in text form - so we can copy it) and expected output?

Comment: I don't see any reason to get index range errors given the code you have shared, are you sure the same `lst` value is getting from the `find_treasure` function to that other code? you are not returning the list so that might be a problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid the error you are getting is not caused by any of the code you have shared, your loop works perfectly well (other than `line.split()` splitting by whitespace which there is none in your file, you probably want `list(line)` or just `line` to split on every character)

This script runs without error demonstrating your issue is in some other part of your code:

```
import io

mock_file = io.StringIO("""WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW.TTT..^^^^...WWWWWWWW
WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW...T..^^^^....WWWWWWWW
WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW......^^^......WWWWWWW
WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW..T.....^^^^..T.WWWWWWW
WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW........^^^^..T.WWWWWWW
WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW........^^^....T.WWWWWWW
WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW........^^^......WWWWWWW
WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW.....^^^^.....WWWWWWWW
WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW.....^^^......WWWWWWWW
WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW....^^......WWWWWWWWW
WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW......^.....WWWWWWWWWW
WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW............WWWWWWWWWWW
WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW....T......WWWWWWWWWWWWW
WWWWW...WWWWWWWWWWWWW..T.T.....WWWWWWWWWWWWW
WWWW..TTT.WWWWWWWWWWW...T.....WWWWWWWWWWWWWW
WWWWW.......WWWWWWWWWWW......WWWWWWWWWWWWWWW
WWWWWWWW...T.WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW
WWWWWWWWW....WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW
WWWWWWWWWW.T.WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW
WWWWWWWWWWW.WWWWWWWWWW.....WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW
WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW....T..WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW
WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW.TTT..WWWWWWWWWWWWWWW
WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW..T..WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW
WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW...WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW
WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW
WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW
WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW
W: WATER                                    
T: TREE                                     
.: GRASS                                    
^: MOUNTAIN""")

def find_treasure(mapfile):
    lst = []
    with mapfile as rf:
        for line in rf:
            lst.append(list(line))
    print(lst)
    
    for i in range(len(lst)):
        for j in range(len(lst[i])):
            if lst[i][j] == 'T':
                print('WHy')
            else:
                print('why am i here why')

find_treasure(mock_file)
```

Because of this I would verify that the `lst` variable is the same in the 2 mentioned sections of code, because range errors would only happen in something different from what you have shown.

Comment: Thank you so much! This was very useful in understanding how split worked etc!

Answer (score 1):

This is not a total response, but I see two problems in your code.

First, as [Tadhg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5827215/tadhg-mcdonald-jensen) mention it, your `find_treasure` does not return any value, that could be causing the `range errors`.

Once you connect that, your other block remains. And the reason that you are reaching your `why am i here why` statement it's cause the `split()` method without a `separator` parameter just split the `blank spaces`. If you want to separate each value from the line, you should use `lst.append(list(line))` this would create a matrix with all the elements of your input to be accessed with `mat[][]`

I hope this helps you =).

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming by "T's arranged in a cross pattern", you mean this:

```
*T*
TTT
*T*
```

Where `*` is anything but a `T`.

So to identify a cross pattern centered at the location `lst[i][j]`, all the indices surrounding it must be equal to `T`.

```
def isCrossAt(lst, i, j):
    return lst[i - 1][j] == 'T' and \
           lst[i + 1][j] == 'T' and \
           lst[i][j - 1] == 'T' and \
           lst[i][j + 1] == 'T' and \
           lst[i][j] == 'T'
```

This means that you only need to check for crosses centered at the second through the second-last row, and the second through the second-last column.

```
def findCrosses(lst):
    for i in range(1, len(lst) - 1):
        row = lst[i]
        for j in range(1, len(row) - 1):
            # Copy the isCrossAt logic here to save a function call
            foundCross = lst[i - 1][j] == 'T' and \
                         lst[i + 1][j] == 'T' and \
                         lst[i][j - 1] == 'T' and \
                         lst[i][j + 1] == 'T' and \
                         lst[i][j] == 'T'
            if foundCross:
                return (i, j)
```

Let's test this using your string.

```
lst = """WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW.TTT..^^^^...WWWWWWWW
WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW...T..^^^^....WWWWWWWW
WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW......^^^......WWWWWWW
WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW..T.....^^^^..T.WWWWWWW
WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW........^^^^..T.WWWWWWW
WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW........^^^....T.WWWWWWW
WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW........^^^......WWWWWWW
WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW.....^^^^.....WWWWWWWW
WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW.....^^^......WWWWWWWW
WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW....^^......WWWWWWWWW
WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW......^.....WWWWWWWWWW
WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW............WWWWWWWWWWW
WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW....T......WWWWWWWWWWWWW
WWWWW...WWWWWWWWWWWWW..T.T.....WWWWWWWWWWWWW
WWWW..TTT.WWWWWWWWWWW...T.....WWWWWWWWWWWWWW
WWWWW.......WWWWWWWWWWW......WWWWWWWWWWWWWWW
WWWWWWWW...T.WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW
WWWWWWWWW....WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW
WWWWWWWWWW.T.WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW
WWWWWWWWWWW.WWWWWWWWWW.....WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW
WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW....T..WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW
WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW.TTT..WWWWWWWWWWWWWWW
WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW..T..WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW
WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW...WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW
WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW
WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW
WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW""".split('\n')

# Now lst is a list of strings, but that doesn't matter 
# because we can obtain characters in a string just like elements in a list
# duck typing FTW!

findCrosses(lst)

# Out: (21, 25)
```